# No access to trash:// neither to recent:// from file manager

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, xfce, trash, nemo

When I try to access *trash* from file manager (*Nautilus* or *Nemo*), I get an error message

```
The folder contents could not be displayed
Sorry, could not display all the contents of "trash": Operation not supported
```

I get the message either clicking on the *Trash icon* or entering `trash://` at the file manager.
The big question mark is that I can smoothly access the *Trash* folders via `~/.local/share/Trash`. Even I can run successfully the command `gio list trash://` in terminal. But the file manager keeps failing.

Additionally, I realized that also with the *Recent* files I have the same issue: I cannot open `recent://` from file manager.

Any idea what is wrong here?
I am using Ubuntu 18.04. with the Xfce Desktop Environment.

Comment: Are you aware that *flavors* of Ubuntu only come with three years of supported life (five years applies to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server but not flavors), so you're asking about a release that only days ago reached it's EOL.  (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ or the latest UWN - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuWeeklyNewsletter/Issue681#Lubuntu_18.04_LTS_End_of_Life_and_Current_Support_Statuses highlights the EOL notices for Lubuntu/Ubuntu-MATE/Kubuntu/Ubuntu-Budgie; Xubuntu didn't announce EOL but refer https://xubuntu.org/release/18-04/ you'll see it's 29 April)

Comment: @guiverc I do not know exactly what you try to tell me. As for me, yes 18.04. might be at EOL, but I expect to keep using this OS at least for the next 2 years, as long as security updates are available. :)

Comment: I'd suggest using `ubuntu-support-status` to check what parts of your system are getting security updates (you'll discover only parts are now supported & thus getting updates, parts are not)...  If you check, `nautilus` still gets security patches, `nemo` & `thunar` being EOL are no longer patched... It's your choice how you secure you want to be.  Your release is now EOL so I (and others) just move on (I post my FYI reminders; as I'm on Ubuntu News team so see knowledge as part of my role thus FYIs)...

Answer (score 0):

for Googler on `Operation not supported`:

[ensure `gvfs` installed correctly](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Trash_management#Trash_creation)

and if for `sudo`:

```bash
#   ref: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gvfs/-/issues/522#note_926138
alias trashllroot='sudo dbus-run-session -- gio trash --list'
```

---

BTW:

---

for Googler on '`gio trash --list` outputs with % and \x' or 'bad encoding for chinese':

```bash
# NOTE: `codecs.escape_decode` is controversial ...
#   ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37059682/7860292
#   ref: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/74773
# only for pipe usage
alias decoded='py -c "import sys, urllib.parse as u, codecs as c; [sys.stdout.write(u.unquote_plus(c.escape_decode(l)[0].decode(\"utf-8\"))) for l in sys.stdin]"'

alias trashls='LANG=en_US.UTF-8 gio list trash://'
alias trashll='gio trash --list | decoded'
```